# Pause and resume caret training in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, parallel-processing, neural-network, r-caret

Let's assume I will do a `caret` training in R, but I want to split this training in two run sessions.

```
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)
library(caret)
set.seed(998)
inTraining <- createDataPartition(Sonar$Class, p = .75, list = FALSE)
training <- Sonar[ inTraining,]
testing  <- Sonar[-inTraining,]

# First run session
nn.partial <- train(Class ~ ., data = training, 
                method = "nnet",
                 max.turns.of.iteration=5) # Non-existent parameter. But represents my goal
```

Let´s assume that instead the `nn` full object I have only a partial object that has training information until the turn 5 (i.e. `nn.partial`). Thus, in future I could run the below code to finish the training job:

```
library(mlbench)
data(Sonar)
library(caret)
set.seed(998)
inTraining <- createDataPartition(Sonar$Class, p = .75, list = FALSE)
training <- Sonar[ inTraining,]
testing  <- Sonar[-inTraining,]

nn <- train(Class ~ ., data = training, 
                 method = "nnet",
                 previous.training=nn.partial) # Non-existent parameter. But represents my goal
```

I am aware that the both `max.turns.of.iteration` and `previous.training` do not exist in the `train` function. I am just trying my best to represent in code what would be the ideal world to accomplish my goal if it was already implemented in `train` function. However, as the parameters are not there, is there a way to achieve this goal (i.e. do the caret training in more than one run) by tricking the function in some way?

I have tried to play with the `trainControl` function without success.

```
t.control <- trainControl(repeats=5)
nn <- train(Class ~ ., data = training, 
                 method = "nnet",
trControl = t.control)
```

By doing that, the number of iteration turns is still much higher than 5, as I would like to obtain in my example.

Comment: The `nnet()` function has the parameters `maxit` and `wts`, which sound much like what you have in mind. These can be passed in caret's `train(..., method = 'nnet')`. That's were I would start, I guess.

Comment: @PinotTiger, apparently `maxit` changes the number of max iterations in each turn and do not the max number of turns

Comment: Please notice that the correct tag is `r-caret`, *not* `caret` (edited).

Comment: In my opinion this would be very hard to implement in caret. But check out mlr3, it enables you to stop and resume training of configurations at will.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am almost certain that this is very complicated to implement in carets current infrastructure. However I will show you how to achieve this sort of thing out of the box with mlr3.

required packages for the example

```
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3tuning)
library(paradox)
```

get an example task and define a learner to be tuned:

```
task_sonar <- tsk('sonar')
learner <- lrn('classif.rpart', predict_type = 'prob')
```

define the hyper parameters to be tuned:

```
ps <- ParamSet$new(list(
  ParamDbl$new("cp", lower = 0.001, upper = 0.1),
  ParamInt$new("minsplit", lower = 1, upper = 10)
))
```

define the tuner and resampling strategy

```
tuner <- tnr("random_search")
cv3 <- rsmp("cv", folds = 3)
```

define the tuning instance

```
instance <- TuningInstance$new(
  task = task_sonar,
  learner = learner,
  resampling = cv3,
  measures = msr("classif.auc"),
  param_set = ps,
  terminator = term("evals", n_evals = 100) #one can combine multiple terminators such as clock time, number of evaluations, early stopping (stagnation), performance reached - ?Terminator
)
```

tune:

```
tuner$tune(instance)
```

now press stop after a second to stop the task in Rstudio

```
instance$archive()

    nr batch_nr  resample_result task_id    learner_id resampling_id iters params tune_x warnings errors classif.auc
 1:  1        1 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7105586
 2:  2        2 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7372720
 3:  3        3 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7335368
 4:  4        4 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7335368
 5:  5        5 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7276246
 6:  6        6 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7111217
 7:  7        7 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.6915560
 8:  8        8 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7452875
 9:  9        9 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7372720
10: 10       10 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7172328
```

in my case it finished 10 iterations of random search.
You can now for instance call

```
save.image()
```

close RStudio and reopen the same project

or  use  `saveRDS`/`readRDS` on the objects you wish to keep

```
saveRDS(instance, "i.rds")
instance <- readRDS("i.rds")
```

after loading the required packages resume training with

```
tuner$tune(instance)
```

stop it again after few seconds:

in my case it finished an additional 12 iterations:

```
instance$archive()

    nr batch_nr  resample_result task_id    learner_id resampling_id iters params tune_x warnings errors classif.auc
 1:  1        1 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7105586
 2:  2        2 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7372720
 3:  3        3 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7335368
 4:  4        4 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7335368
 5:  5        5 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7276246
 6:  6        6 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7111217
 7:  7        7 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.6915560
 8:  8        8 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7452875
 9:  9        9 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7372720
10: 10       10 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7172328
11: 11       11 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7325289
12: 12       12 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7105586
13: 13       13 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7215133
14: 14       14 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.6915560
15: 15       15 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.6915560
16: 16       16 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7335368
17: 17       17 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7276246
18: 18       18 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7111217
19: 19       19 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7172328
20: 20       20 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7276246
21: 21       21 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7105586
22: 22       22 <ResampleResult>   sonar classif.rpart            cv     3 <list> <list>        0      0   0.7276246
```

Run it again without pressing stop

```
tuner$tune(instance)
```

and it will finish the 100 evals

Limitation: The above example splits the tuning (evaluation of hyper-parameters) to multiple sessions). However it does not split one training instance into multiple sessions - very few packages support this kind of thing in R - keras/tensorflow are the only one I know of.

However regardless of the length of one training instance for an algorithm, the tuning (evaluation of hyper parameters) of such an algorithm takes much more time so it is more advantageous to be able to pause/resume the tuning as in the above example.

If you find this interesting here are some resources to learn mlr3

https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/
https://mlr3gallery.mlr-org.com/

Take a look also at mlr3pipelines - https://mlr3pipelines.mlr-org.com/articles/introduction.html