# How to prevent Rstudio from crashing?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rstudio, r-caret

I am currently working on a Machine Learning project for my Exam. My computer has 32gb RAM, and have a 12 core I7. My Session Info is given below,

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8      
 [2] LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8      
 [8] LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
[12] LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
[6] datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] forcats_0.5.0   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.2    
 [4] purrr_0.3.4     readr_1.4.0     tidyr_1.1.2    
 [7] tibble_3.0.4    tidyverse_1.3.0 here_1.0.1     
[10] caret_6.0-86    ggplot2_3.3.3   lattice_0.20-41

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.5           lubridate_1.7.9.2   
 [3] class_7.3-17         assertthat_0.2.1    
 [5] rprojroot_2.0.2      ipred_0.9-9         
 [7] foreach_1.5.1        R6_2.5.0            
 [9] cellranger_1.1.0     plyr_1.8.6          
[11] backports_1.2.1      reprex_0.3.0        
[13] stats4_4.0.3         httr_1.4.2          
[15] pillar_1.4.7         rlang_0.4.10        
[17] readxl_1.3.1         rstudioapi_0.13     
[19] data.table_1.13.6    rpart_4.1-15        
[21] Matrix_1.3-2         splines_4.0.3       
[23] gower_0.2.2          munsell_0.5.0       
[25] broom_0.7.3          compiler_4.0.3      
[27] modelr_0.1.8         pkgconfig_2.0.3     
[29] nnet_7.3-14          tidyselect_1.1.0    
[31] prodlim_2019.11.13   codetools_0.2-18    
[33] fansi_0.4.1          crayon_1.3.4        
[35] dbplyr_2.0.0         withr_2.3.0         
[37] MASS_7.3-53          recipes_0.1.15      
[39] ModelMetrics_1.2.2.2 grid_4.0.3          
[41] nlme_3.1-151         jsonlite_1.7.2      
[43] gtable_0.3.0         lifecycle_0.2.0     
[45] DBI_1.1.0            magrittr_2.0.1      
[47] pROC_1.16.2          scales_1.1.1        
[49] cli_2.2.0            stringi_1.5.3       
[51] reshape2_1.4.4       fs_1.5.0            
[53] timeDate_3043.102    xml2_1.3.2          
[55] ellipsis_0.3.1       generics_0.1.0      
[57] vctrs_0.3.6          lava_1.6.8.1        
[59] iterators_1.0.13     tools_4.0.3         
[61] glue_1.4.2           hms_0.5.3           
[63] survival_3.2-7       colorspace_2.0-0    
[65] rvest_0.3.6          haven_2.3.1
```

My data is 50.000 x 30, and initially I trained my models with the following code for both classification and regression problems,

```
models <- list()

# Generate cluster
genCluster <- makeCluster(
  spec = detectCores() - 1
)

registerDoParallel(
  cl = genCluster
)

set.seed(1903)
system.time(
  for (i in 1:length(Algorithms)){
    
   
    
    # train models
    suppressWarnings(
      models[[i]] <- train(
        form = Y ~ .,
        data = df,
        method = Algorithms[i],
        trControl = trainControl(
          method = "repeatedcv",
          number = 10,
          repeats = 3,
          index = myFolds,
          verboseIter = F,
          allowParallel = T
        )
      )
    )
    
    
  }
)

stopCluster(
  cl = genCluster
)

}
```

Before I run the entire script, I take a random sample from my data, to test my script to see if it works. So in my test run I usually run with 2000 observations. This works, usually, like a charm.

However, whenever I use the entire dataset I either get a unserialize error, or some related "dead"-worker error. If this doesnt happen, then my R Session just crashes.
**Note:** This also happens when I run the same codes on a 64 core with 320gb RAM instance through my University Supercomputer.

**How I tried to solve the problem**

1. Instead of using the max number of cores, I used the number that was equal to k-folds - So 10. This helped (a bit) on the worker/core related errors. It seems that these errors are rather random for my case. However, R Session crashes persisted.
2. Instead of Using R Studio, I decided to execute my scripts through the Terminal, however, as every relative path in my scripts is in the root project directory, going through 30+ scripts to change this seems out of proportion as RStudio *should* work.
   For some odd reason, `setwd()`through the R terminal does not affect child scripts!
3. Before executing each heavy script I tried to clean environment and memory.

```
rm(
  list=setdiff(
    ls(), 
    c("importantParameters",
      "train.data",
      "estimateFoo",
      "bestPick")
  )
)


gc(full = T, verbose = F)
```

This didn't change anything regards to crashes, or worker/core-related errors.

**My new approach**

After giving up on this, I took a new approach using `mclapply` instead. It is considerably slower, and does not work as I thought it would. Please note that I have `alllowParallel = F` in this version, as I expected `mclappy` to run all models on the list simultaneously. Which isnt the case, as far as I can see from my system monitor

```
estimateFoo <- function(algorithms, equation, cores, plot = F, data, trainObject, type = NULL, plot.name = NULL, metric = c("RMSE")){
  
  # Packages
  require(parallel)
  require(caret)
  require(tidyverse)
  
  # This function estimates all algorithms. Must be provided by a vector of characters.
  # FULL TrainObjects from Caret has to be provided.
  # If plot == T it plots in a tryCatch fashion, to avoid Errors.
  # NOTE: Type has to be oneof classification or regression (As the folders are named.)
  
  trainedModels <- suppressWarnings(mclapply(
      X = algorithms,
      FUN = function(x){
        
        tryCatch(
          train(
            form   = equation,
            data   = data,
            method = x,
            trControl = trainObject
          )
        )
        
      },
      mc.cores = cores
    )
  )
  
  
  
  # Identify TryErrors and remove them. Otherwise the
  # script breaks down
  tryErrorIndicator <- sapply(trainedModels, FUN = class) %in% c("try-error", "NULL")
   
  # # Remove TryErrors
  trainedModels <- trainedModels[!tryErrorIndicator]
  
  # Name List Elements
  names(trainedModels) <- algorithms[!tryErrorIndicator]
  
  # NOTE: It ignores NULL elements, which are due
  # to dead workers. This indicator removes them.
  deadWorker <- which(sapply(trainedModels, is.null))
  
  # If plot is true; then it plots all models and saves
  if (isTRUE(plot)){

    # Generate resamples; and remove those that are empty
    modelResample <- trainedModels[-deadWorker] %>%
      resamples()

    print(
      dotplot(
        modelResample,
        metric = metric,
        scales = list(x = list(relation = "free"),
                      y = list(cex = 1.2))
      )
    )


    dev.copy(pdf, here("results","models", paste(type), paste(plot.name)))
    dev.off()



  }
  
  return(
    trainedModels[-deadWorker]
  )
}
```

This new approach, albeit slower, works. However, my RSession *still* crashes!

What should I do? How do I **properly** do Machine Learning in R without losing my mind, and wasting 4 days trying to have R running all my codes without crashing?

Comment: I realize that my post is not as 'general' as it should be. However, Im sure that Im not the only one with this problem; and if we can find a solution we could compile this post into a "how-to"-post, such that it can benefit everyone other than just solve my problem!

Comment: what does `htop` show in the run up to the crash? I work in terminal only and crash in one crashes the other...have you looked at /var/crash/whoopsie output? Clearly I'm thinking this is a memory problem and note your effort to clear environment. perhaps slip a `gc()[i]` in,

Comment: I would try mlr3 I found it more stable in parallel, and it works with just one additional line of code: https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/parallelization.html

Comment: @Chris I am not familiar with `htop` - So you suggest to do `gc()` after each iteration?

Comment: ubuntu focal apt-get, `htop` interactive process viewer (terminal), I use to see why I'm crashing 8G of memory running models, or attempting. the gc()[i] or gc()[x] might or not free any unused objects spawned & forgotten. Where to tuck it in, place it in the `)` hierarchy eludes me, especially where tracking the anonymous function index...Something of a voodoo approach, unfortunately.

Comment: @missuse - mlr3 seems interesting. However does it play along with Caret? Or were you suggesting it instead of mclapply?

Comment: This is a wild guess; Currently monitoring my System, while running a GBM; On a single core with a random gridsearch of length 3 the R session takes up 14 GB of RAM. If I were to run this on two cores, it would amount to 28 GB of RAM - and this is basically a Linear Releationship considering Im running 10 Folds with 3 repetitions; 30 cores would make sense to assign to this process roughly amounting to 360 GB of RAM.

Comment: mlr3 is an independent universe from caret with a bunch of packages for different thing related to ML. It is contemporary, actively updated, and offers many features not present in caret. That being said it will take some while till you get used to it if you are accustomed to caret since its R6 based. See some of my answers to understand the capabilities: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61967941/pause-and-resume-caret-training-in-r, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60490750/pca-within-cross-validation-however-only-with-a-subset-of-variables, also: https://mlr3gallery.mlr-org.com/

Comment: @missuse Hi again, I was browsing Journal of Statistical Software for the mlr3 package - and I cant seem to find anything. This package is still not 'published' is it? The integration with data.table caught my interest, and I am looking for a comprehensive manual!

Comment: @Serkan mlr3 is published on CRAN. It is split into multiple packages, easiest way to install them is to install [`mlr3verse`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlr3verse/index.html). The journal article about mlr3 is [here](https://joss.theoj.org/papers/10.21105/joss.01903), To learn mlr3 its best to read the [book](https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/) and check the [gallery examples](https://mlr3gallery.mlr-org.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll answer my own question with help from the comments I've gotten. If anyone has some to contribute with, or find this post irrelevant - please flag it for deletion.

1. R Sessions crashes mainly due to lack of memory. So if you are training models with grid searching, then you need a rough estimate of how much RAM it will occupy in order to run it smoothly. Whether it is possible to limit RAM usage by changing some of the arguments in the functions like setting `returnData = F`, I have not tested due to time constraints.
2. Training your models with `allowParallel = T`, will split the amount of RAM equally between workers and therefor RAM usage increases approximately in a linear fashion such that RAM is quickly used up when training models simultaneously.

The solution, therefore, thus far must be to either get more RAM, reduce data-size or limit your grid search.

Do **not** use `allowParallel = T` without considering the amount of RAM you have. This was new to me. I hope this helps you, as well as it helped me.