# Use of R6 class

Tags: r, r6

I just started reading about R6 classes in R. And I found below code where they tried to explain about R6.

```
Person <- R6Class(
  classname = "Person",
  public = list(
    name = NULL,
    age = NULL,
    desire = NULL,
    initialize = function(name = NA, age = NA, desire = NA) {
      self$name <- name
      self$age <- age
      self$desire <- desire
      self$greet()
    },
    set_age = function(val) {
      self$age <- val
      cat("Age of ", self$name, " is:  ", val, ".\n", sep = "")
    },
    set_desire = function(val) {
      self$desire <- val
      cat("Desire of ", self$name, " is:  ", val, ".\n", sep = "")
    },
    greet = function() {
      cat(paste0("Hello, my name is ", self$name, ".\n"))
    },
    df1 = function(){
      data.frame(c11 = self$name, c2 = self$age, c3 = self$desire)
    }
  )
)
```

I am still not convinced why there is a need to create above class. We can anyhow create these variables separately right (Like name, age and all). Can anyone explain?

Comment: This example is a toy, it does not illustrate why at all would anyone use R6 in r given the much simpler S3 and S4 systems. However R6 has great advantages for complex projects. One of the best implemented R6 packages in my opinion is mlr3 (not affiliated just a user) - https://mlr3.mlr-org.com/. For instance check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61967941/pause-and-resume-caret-training-in-r/62080309. How would you implement this sort of thing using S3 or S4?

Comment: Also check this: https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/pipelines.html, how would this be implemented using S3? In fact similar was implemented using S3 in mlr: https://mlr.mlr-org.com/ but it became limiting. Or for instance torch: https://torch.mlverse.org/ in R or keras: https://keras.rstudio.com/. Its not at all clear how these would be implemented using S3 or S4. In fact it seems to me that the bottleneck of R was lack of something like R6.

Comment: Although @missuse provided some great examples,  I've implemented R6 classes for manual MCMC of 3D transformations (based on 3D coordinates of a product) that emulated a manufacturing process. I used R6 primarily because once I was comfortable with it, it was easier than S3 or S4. As far as the parent class, I only initialized data in that class and only data I read in, after that I created variables as needed (like regular code).  I'm not going to create methods that make the code more complicated than it already is. I set all of the `self` vars with one method `initialize = function(...)`.